# Expansion issues again

Tags: expl3, expansion, tikz-matrix, token-lists, l3seq

I seem to keep encountering the same issue. In my attempt to learn more about expansions I have written a program that starts with a sequence of 1s and then after each step increments it to generate a sequence of 2s, etc. All the different sequences generated then must be displayed in a `tikz` matrix in the following format:

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{ m }  % indices   
{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpc_seq { #1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq - 1}
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {##1} = 1$} \&}
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq} = 1$} \\}
    \int_new:N \l_tmpc_int
    \int_new:N \l_tmpd_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpc_int {4}
    \int_step_inline:nnn {2} {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
    {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpc_int {\l_tmpc_int * 4}
    }
    \int_log:N \l_tmpc_int
    \int_step_inline:nnn {2} {\l_tmpc_int} 
    {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {##1}
        \int_log:N \l_tmpb_int
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq{####1}}
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpd_int { \int_eval:n  {\l_tmpa_int + 1}}
            \int_log:N \l_tmpd_int
            \seq_set_item:NnV \l_tmpb_seq {####1} \l_tmpd_int 
        }
        \seq_log:N \l_tmpb_seq
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq - 1}
        {
            \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {####1} = \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1} $} \&}
        }
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq} = \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq}$} \\}
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_eval:n {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1}}}
            \int_log:N \l_tmpa_int
            \seq_set_item:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {####1} \l_tmpa_int 
        }
        \seq_log:N \l_tmpa_seq
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0ex]current~bounding~box.center)}]
        \matrix(m) [
          matrix~of~nodes,
           ampersand~replacement=\&,
           column~sep=1ex,
           nodes~in~empty~cells,
           nodes={
             shape=rectangle,
             minimum~height=3ex,
             anchor=center
           },
         ]{
            \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
         };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_item:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
    \indexprod{i,j}    
\]

\end{document}
```

but of course the result is,

[image]

since the commands in the token list are frozen and  commands like `\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1}` evaluate with their latest values which happen to be equal to 16.

I have gone through the documentation trying to find a way to change expressions like,

```
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\mbox{\tiny $ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {####1} = \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1} $} \&}
```

so that I use the values of `\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1}` but I have not been able to make a breakthrough.

Any ideas more than welcome...

Comment: same issue as before `\tl_put_right:Nn` is putting variable references in the sequence so when you use the sequence you just get the same value each time, you want `Nx`  to make a sequence of values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `\tl_put_right:Nx` so the argument is fully expanded. But you don't want to fully expand `\mbox` and `\tiny`, so a robust wrapper is needed. A command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` is never expanded in `e`-expansion or `x`-expansion.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tinybox}{m}{\mbox{\tiny#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{ m }  % indices   
{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpc_seq { #1 }
    \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}
    }
    \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq - 1}
    {
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tinybox{$ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {##1} = 1$} \&}
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tinybox{$ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq} = 1$} \\}
    \int_new:N \l_tmpc_int
    \int_new:N \l_tmpd_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpc_int {4}
    \int_step_inline:nnn {2} {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
    {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpc_int {\l_tmpc_int * 4}
    }
    \int_log:N \l_tmpc_int
    \int_step_inline:nnn {2} {\l_tmpc_int} 
    {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {##1}
        \int_log:N \l_tmpb_int
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq{####1}}
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpd_int { \int_eval:n  {\l_tmpa_int + 1}}
            \int_log:N \l_tmpd_int
            \seq_set_item:NnV \l_tmpb_seq {####1} \l_tmpd_int 
        }
        \seq_log:N \l_tmpb_seq
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq - 1}
        {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tinybox{$ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {####1} = \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1} $} \&}
        }
        \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\tinybox{$ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq} = \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq}$} \\}
        \int_step_inline:nn {\seq_count:N \l_tmpc_seq}
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\int_eval:n {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq{####1}}}
            \int_log:N \l_tmpa_int
            \seq_set_item:NnV \l_tmpa_seq {####1} \l_tmpa_int 
        }
        \seq_log:N \l_tmpa_seq
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0ex]current~bounding~box.center)}]
        \matrix(m) [
          matrix~of~nodes,
           ampersand~replacement=\&,
           column~sep=1ex,
           nodes~in~empty~cells,
           nodes={
             shape=rectangle,
             minimum~height=3ex,
             anchor=center
           },
         ]{
            \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
         };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_item:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
    \indexprod{i,j}    
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might enjoy studying the following simpler code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tinybox}{m}{\mbox{\tiny#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{ O{16} m }  % indices   
 {
  % the indices
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \tinybox{$##1=\int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int }$} }
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \& } }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpb_tl \exp_not:N \\ }
   }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0ex]current~bounding~box.center)}]
    \matrix(m) [
      matrix~of~nodes,
      ampersand~replacement=\&,
      column~sep=1ex,
      nodes~in~empty~cells,
      nodes={
        shape=rectangle,
        minimum~height=3ex,
        anchor=center
      },
    ]{
      \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \indexprod{i,j}\qquad
  \indexprod[5]{i,j,k}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments about the above code. If we `\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq` and `\seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq` after they're set we get

```
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {i}
>  {j}.

The sequence \l_tmpb_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\tinybox {$i=\int_eval:n {\l_tmpa_int }$}}
>  {\tinybox {$j=\int_eval:n {\l_tmpa_int }$}}.
```

Now add `\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl` and `\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl` after they're set in the `\prg_replicate:nn` loop: at the first iteration we get

```
> \l_tmpb_tl=\tinybox {$i=\int_eval:n {\l_tmpa_int }$}\&\tinybox
{$j=\int_eval:n {\l_tmpa_int }$}.

> \l_tmpa_tl=\tinybox {$i=1$}\&\tinybox {$j=1$}\\.
```

This uses the fact that the items in the sequence are returned with `\exp_not:n` around them, so `\tl_set:Nx` just arrives at the “surface” token list; but after `\tl_put_right:Nx` the items *are* fully expanded. In this case I exploit that the items in `\l_tmpa_seq` are “expansion safe”. Other use cases might need other cares.

#### Safer version

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tinybox}{m}{\mbox{\tiny#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tbinnermatrix}{m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \matrix(m) [
      matrix of nodes,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
      column sep=1ex,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={
        shape=rectangle,
        minimum height=3ex,
        anchor=center
      },
    ]{ #1 };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{ O{16} m }  % indices   
 {
  \tedblack_indexprod:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\cs_set_eq:NN \tedblack_innermatrix:n \tbinnermatrix
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tedblack_mymatrix:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tedblack_indexprod:nn
 {
  % the indices
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \tinybox{$\exp_not:n { ##1 }=####1$} }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \& } }
  \cs_set:NV \__tedblack_temp:n \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \__tedblack_temp:n { ##1 } \exp_not:N \\ }
   }
  \tedblack_innermatrix:V \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \indexprod{i,j}\qquad
  \indexprod[5]{i,j,\mathbf{k}}
\]

\end{document}
```

This not only shows that “risky” commands such as `\mathbf` are safe in the argument to `\indexprod`, but also shows better programming style where there is a distinction between user level commands and internal functions.

The “matrix building” command is taken outside `\ExplSyntaxOn`, which is always best when Ti*k*Z is involved. An internal version is defined later, with the possibility to define a variant thereof.

A “local” function is defined so it can be used to substitute the current value in the `\int_step_inline:nn` loop.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tinybox}{m}{\mbox{\tiny#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tbinnermatrix}{m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \matrix(m) [
      matrix of nodes,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
      column sep=1ex,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={
        shape=rectangle,
        minimum height=3ex,
        anchor=center
      },
    ]{ #1 };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{ O{16} m }  % indices   
 {
  \tedblack_indexprod:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\cs_set_eq:NN \tedblack_innermatrix:n \tbinnermatrix
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tedblack_innermatrix:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tedblack_indexprod:nn
 {
  % the indices
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \tinybox{$\exp_not:n { ##1 }=####1$} }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \& } }
  \cs_set:NV \__tedblack_temp:n \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \__tedblack_temp:n { ##1 } \exp_not:N \\ }
   }
  \tedblack_innermatrix:V \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \indexprod{i,j}\qquad
  \indexprod[5]{i,j,\mathbf{k}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What can I say? It always happens that mastering a subject means that the solutions given seem more than simple.

Comment: @TedBlack Look at the added code. 

Comment: I guess `\tinybox` is robust because `NewDocumentCommand` is never expanded.

Comment: The added code uses `\l_tmpb_seq ` and `\l_tmpa_int ` before they are set. How is this possible? I understand that `\prg_replicate` creates multiple copies but in your code it is run after the `\seq_set_map` that uses them.

Comment: @TedBlack When in doubt, use `\tl_show:N` (or alike commands).

Comment: @TedBlack I added some comments

Comment: As usual I am reading latex3 code as if it was C code... You initially set `\l_tmpb_seq` to contain expressions that include `\int_eval:n { \l_tmpa_int }` ; these are just unexpanded tokens even though they contain `int_eval`. Then in the `\prg_replicate` loop, `\l_tmpa_int` is incremented and the contents of `\l_tmpb_seq` are expanded by using `\tl_set:Nx`.

Comment: @TedBlack Yes, that's it. I added another version that you can study.

Comment: The new version is a bit tricky... First, in the command `\tinybox{$\exp_not: {##1}=####1$}` `##1` is the item from `seq_set_map` but what is `####1`? I understand that you use the variant of `cs_set`  so that `__tedblack_temp` is the whole list of commands contained in `l_tmpa_tl`. But then in the `int_step_inline` loop somehow the same command takes an argument equal to the current value of `#1` which is the set of letters that is the first input of `ted_black_indexprod`. How  can `ted_black_temp` suddenly accept input parameters?

Comment: @TedBlack  Do `\cs_show:N \__tedblack_temp:n` after setting it to see the magic!

Comment: Yes it works. I still don't understand how the `####1` part in `\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \tinybox{$\exp_not:n { ##1 }=####1$} }` gets converted to `##1` (in fact I dont understand how the program can accept something like `####1`. Then as soon as you assign `\cs_set:NV \__tedblack_temp:n \l_tmpa_tl` as if by magic the token list contains `#1` instead of `##1` !!

Comment: @TedBlack That's just how [TeX and nesting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463) works. Here's even [a LaTeX3 example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56961). And there's also Q&A about [a l3seq usecase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124949) as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel so after `\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq`  `##1` is replaced by the content and `####1` becomes `##1` , and after `\cs_set:NV \__tedblack_temp:n \l_tmpa_tl`  `##1` becomes `#1`?

Comment: @TedBlack Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: By the way what is  ‘exp_not’ doing in ‘ $\exp_not:n { ##1 }=####1’ ?

Comment: @TedBlack defensive programming to allow for dangerous tokens in the argument

Comment: OK so `##1` is replaced by `i` or `\mathbf{k}` and `\exp_not` makes sure `\mathbf` is not expanded further... I would think that since `\seq_set_map:NNn` takes `n` as its third argument this is already taken care of.

Comment: @TedBlack But later we use `\tl_put_right:Nx`

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is an exercise in LaTeX3 but I want to offer my PGFKeys version of it.

Value-keys also just store tokens which we can alter with ([amongst other](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#sec-87.2))

- `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/key}{<value>}` and
- `\pgfkeysaddvalue{/key}{<prefix>}{<suffix>}`

or their handler alternatives ([amongst other](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#sec-87.4.5))

- `/key/.initial=<value>` (or `/key=<value>` if the `/key` was initialized beofrehand)
- `/key/.add={<prefix>}{<suffix>}`,
- `/key/.prefix=<prefix>` and
- `/key/.append=<suffix>`.

An ungrouped PGFFor loop can be achieved via the `.list` handler which allows us to repeatedly use a key.

By nesting `.list` applications it is possible to build a matrix.
We just need to make sure we put one less `\pgfmatrixnextcell` (the `&`/`\&` of it all) in than number of columns.
This is done by not putting it in on the first cell of a row. That's why `/tikz/matrix/create cell` gets redefined in its own definition.

I've chosen `anchor = base` for the nodes inside the matrix so that their baselines align. The matrix itself is anchored at its center which means its center will be at *y* = 0pt which is the value chosen for the `baseline`.

---

Instead of using `i, j, \mathbf{k}` as the list, you can use

```
\indexprod[
  indexprod/rows=5,
  column 3/.style={set matrix macro={$\mathbf{##2}=##1$}}
]{i, j, k}
```

for the same effect. Of course, you can use another top-level interface that is less verbose than that.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  matrix node/.style 2 args={
    name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn},
  set matrix macro/.code=
    \protected\def\tikzmatrixcell##1##2{\node[matrix node={##1}{##2}]{#1};},
  set matrix macro'/.code=\protected\def\tikzmatrixcell##1##2{#1},
  create matrix/.code 2 args=% quicker https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692610
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/matrix/content}{}%
    \pgfkeysdef{/tikz/matrix/create rows}{%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix/reset create cell/.@cmd}\pgfeov
      \pgfkeysdef{/tikz/matrix/create columns}{%
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix/create cell/.@cmd}{##1}{####1}\pgfeov}%
      \tikzset{matrix/create columns/.list={#2}}%
      \pgfkeysaddvalue{/tikz/matrix/content}{}{\pgfmatrixendrow}}%
    \tikzset{matrix/create rows/.list={#1},
      node contents=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix/content}},
  matrix/reset create cell/.code=
    \pgfkeysdefargs{/tikz/matrix/create cell}{##1##2}{%
      \pgfkeysaddvalue{/tikz/matrix/content}{}{\tikzmatrixcell{##1}{##2}}%
      \pgfkeysdefargs{/tikz/matrix/create cell}{####1####2}{%
        \pgfkeysaddvalue{/tikz/matrix/content}{}{%
          \pgfmatrixnextcell\tikzmatrixcell{####1}{####2}}}}}

\tikzset{
  indexprod/rows/.initial=16,
  indexprod/list/.initial={1, ..., \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/indexprod/rows}},
  every indexprod diagram/.style={
    baseline=+0pt, column sep=1ex, set matrix macro={$##2 = ##1$},
    every outer matrix/.style={shape=rectangle, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt},
    every matrix/.style={
      anchor=center, nodes={shape=rectangle, anchor=base, minimum height=3ex}}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexprod}{O{} m}{%
  \tikz[every indexprod diagram,#1]
    \matrix[create matrix/.expanded=
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/indexprod/list}}{\unexpanded{#2}}];}
\begin{document}
\indexprod{i, j}
\quad
\indexprod[indexprod/rows=5]{i, j, \mathbf{k}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]