# Calendar in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar

I've been searching for a while how to make a calendar with LaTeX and I've found some templates, however none of them fitted my needs. What I want is just a basic monthly calendar with some space for each day in order to add some reminders, tasks, birthdays, etc. I would like to plan my activities monthly in an easy way and print them then in a page.

I've seen this template surfing the internet, which I think is pretty neat, clear and not too old-styled, however I've been unable to find the code, so I would like to know if some of you could give me a hint in how to make it.

[image: Latex Calendar]

Comment: Some years ago I created calendar sheets for my filofax. I wasn't able to implement a pure LaTeX solution so I used PHP to generate the code. I guess, I'd use Excel or Python now to calculate the weekdays and TikZ for the layout.

Comment: It looks like [this example on texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/)

Comment: Yes, it is pretty much the same, I'm currently figuring out how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: @esdd, maybe you paste the code here as answer, otherwise I wonder how this question can be closed.

Comment: I have typeset this yearly calendar, http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/2014-calendar.pdf Each cell is one node in TikZ, but I doubt it would help you with your monthly calendar.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a copy of the code from [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/) (Author: Hakon Malmedal):

```
% Birthday calendar
% Author: Hakon Malmedal
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,fit}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10199/4771
\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/Mandag,1/Tirsdag,2/Onsdag,3/Torsdag,%
                         4/Fredag,5/Lørdag,6/Søndag} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa-\cellwidth/2}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[above=-0.5ex,day heading]{\l};%
      }
    }{}%
  }%
]
\makeatother%
%% End

%% Adapted from pgf source
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \translate{\ifcase#1\or Januar\or Februar\or Mars\or April\or
    Mai\or Juni\or Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or
    November\or Desember\fi}%
}

\makeatletter
\tikzstyle{month label above centered}=[%
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      {
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgf@xb=\tikz@lib@cal@width\pgf@xa%
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xb=.5\pgf@xb%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%
        \pgftransformxshift{-\cellwidth/2}%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{0.333\pgf@y}
        \tikzmonthcode%
      }
    }{}},
  every month/.append style={anchor=base}
]
\makeatother
%% End

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56214/4771
%%
% first of all we define the user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtext}{ m }{ \bdaycal_input_add:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtextyear}{ mm }{ \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showtext}{ }{ \bdaycal_output_direct: }

% allocate variable:
% a sequence for global storage of the inputs;
\seq_new:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq

% store globally an input in the sequence
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add:n #1
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 ~ ( \int_to_arabic:n
    { \pgfcalendarifdateyear - #2 } ) }
 }

% how to output in direct order; we simply do a mapping function calling
% \bdaycal_print:n after incrementing the counter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bdaycal_output_direct:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq
   {
    \bdaycal_print:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq
 }

% the printing macro; change here for adapting to your wishes
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_print:n #1
 {
  #1 \par
 }
%% End

%% Knuth's AoCP, vol 1, 2nd ed, pp 155--156
\int_new:N \l_easter_Y_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_G_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_C_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_X_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_Z_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_D_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_E_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_N_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_M_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_julian_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \easter_sunday:n {

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Y_int { #1 }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_G_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 19 } + 1
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_C_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 100 } + 1
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_X_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 3 * \l_easter_C_int } { 4 } - 12
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Z_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 8 * \l_easter_C_int + 5 } { 25 } - 5
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_D_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 5 * \l_easter_Y_int } { 4 } - \l_easter_X_int - 10
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_E_int {
    \int_mod:nn { 11 * \l_easter_G_int + 20 + \l_easter_Z_int
      - \l_easter_X_int } { 30 }
  }

  % \int_mod:nn behaves strangely.
  \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } < { 0 }
  {
    \int_add:Nn \l_easter_E_int { 30 }
  }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_E_int } = { 25 }
  { % true
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_G_int } > { 11 }
    { % true
      \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
    }
  }
  { % false
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } = { 24 }
    { % true
      \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
    }
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 44 - \l_easter_E_int }

  \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_N_int } < { 21 }
  { % true
    \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 30 }
  }

  \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int {
    7 - \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_D_int + \l_easter_N_int } { 7 }
  }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_N_int } > { 31 }
  { % true
    \int_sub:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 31 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 4 } % April
  }
  { % false
    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 3 } % March
  }

  \pgfcalendardatetojulian { \l_easter_Y_int -
     \l_easter_M_int - \l_easter_N_int
  } { \l_easter_julian_day_int }

}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Easter/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Easter/.code =
  {
    \easter_sunday:n { \pgfcalendarifdateyear }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \pgfcalendarifdatejulian }
    =  {\l_easter_julian_day_int + #1}
    { \pgfcalendarmatchestrue }
  }
}

\int_new:N \l_advent_Y_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_julian_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \advent_sunday:n {

  \int_set:Nn \l_advent_Y_int { #1 }

  \pgfcalendardatetojulian { \l_advent_Y_int - 12 - 25 } {
    \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int }

  \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday { \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int } {
    \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int }

  \int_set:Nn \l_advent_julian_day_int {
    \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int - \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int - 22 }

}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Advent/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Advent/.code =
  {
    \advent_sunday:n { \pgfcalendarifdateyear }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \pgfcalendarifdatejulian }
    =  {\l_advent_julian_day_int + #1}
    { \pgfcalendarmatchestrue }
  }
}

%% http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/week.php#calcweekno
\int_new:N \l_week_number_year_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_month_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_day_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_a_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_b_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_c_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_s_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_e_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_f_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_g_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_d_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_n_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_W_int

\cs_new:Nn \week_number:nnn {

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_year_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_month_int { #2 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_day_int { #3 }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_month_int } < { 3 } % jan or feb
  { % true

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_a_int { \l_week_number_year_int - 1 }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
      \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

    \int_zero:N \l_week_number_e_int

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int - 1
      + 31 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 1 ) }

  } % end true
  { % false

    \int_set_eq:NN \l_week_number_a_int \l_week_number_year_int

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
      \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
      + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
      \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_e_int { \l_week_number_s_int + 1 }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int
      + \int_div_truncate:nn {
        153 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 3 ) + 2 } { 5 }
      + 58 + \l_week_number_s_int }

  } % end false

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_g_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_a_int + \l_week_number_b_int } { 7 }  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_d_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_f_int + \l_week_number_g_int
      - \l_week_number_e_int } { 7 }  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_n_int {
    \l_week_number_f_int + 3 - \l_week_number_d_int }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } < { 0 }
  { %true

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 53
      - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_g_int
        - \l_week_number_s_int } { 5 } }

  } % end true
  { % false

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } > { 364
      + \l_week_number_s_int }
    { % true

      \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 1 }

    } % end true
    { % false

      \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {
          \l_week_number_n_int } { 7 } + 1 }

    } % end false

  } % end false

}

\definecolor{roed}{rgb}{0.937254901961,0.16862745098,0.176470588235}
\definecolor{blaa}{rgb}{0,0.156862745098,0.407843137255}

\newsavebox{\flagNO}
\savebox{\flagNO}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[roed] rectangle (6pt,6pt);
  \fill[roed,yshift=10pt] rectangle (6pt,6pt);
  \fill[roed,xshift=10pt] rectangle (12pt,6pt);
  \fill[roed,xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt] rectangle (12pt,6pt);
  \fill[blaa,yshift=7pt] rectangle (22pt,2pt);
  \fill[blaa,xshift=7pt] rectangle (2pt,16pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/week~number/.code =
  {
    \week_number:nnn { 
      \pgfcalendarifdateyear } { 
      \pgfcalendarifdatemonth } { 
      \pgfcalendarifdateday }
    \addtext{ Uke ~ \int_to_arabic:n { \l_week_number_W_int } }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfkeys{/tikz/flag-flying day/.code =
  {
    \draw (-\cellwidth,0) node [above right,font=\Huge]
    {\resizebox{!}{0.8ex}{\usebox{\flagNO}}};
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/observance/.code =
  {
    \addtext{#1}
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/anniversary/.code 2 args=\addtextyear{#1}{#2}}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day code =
  {
    \node (lower right) at (0,0) [above left,font=\Huge] {\tikzdaytext};
    \node (upper left) at (-\cellwidth,\cellheight)
    [below right,align=left,text width=\cellwidth-\pgflinewidth,
    font=\tiny,black] {\showtext};
    \node (lower left) at (-\cellwidth,0) {};
    \node[rounded corners, draw,
          fit=(lower right) (upper left) (lower left),
          inner sep=1mm] {};
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/inner sep = 0pt}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day xshift=\cellwidth+2mm+2mm}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day yshift=\cellheight+2mm+2mm}

\newlength{\cellheight}
\setlength{\cellheight}{25mm}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{35mm}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \calendar[dates=2012-05-01 to 2012-05-last,
            week list,
            month label above centered,
            month text=\textsc{\%mt \%y0},
            day headings={font=\footnotesize},
            day letter headings]
  if (Monday,
      equals=01-01,
      equals=02-01,
      equals=03-01,
      equals=04-01,
      equals=05-01,
      equals=06-01,
      equals=07-01,
      equals=08-01,
      equals=09-01,
      equals=10-01,
      equals=11-01,
      equals=12-01) [week number]
  if (Sunday,
      Easter=-3, % Maundy Thursday
      Easter=-2, % Good Friday
      Easter,    % Easter Sunday
      Easter=1,  % Easter Monday
      Easter=39, % Feast of the Ascension
      Easter=49, % Pentecost
      Easter=50, % Whit Monday
      equals=01-01,
      equals=05-01,
      equals=05-17,
      equals=12-25,
      equals=12-26) [red]
  if (equals=01-01,
      equals=01-21,
      equals=02-06,
      equals=02-21,
      equals=05-01,
      equals=05-08,
      equals=05-17,
      equals=06-07,
      equals=07-04,
      equals=07-20,
      equals=07-29,
      equals=08-19,
      equals=12-25,
      Easter,
      Easter=49) [flag-flying day]
  if (equals=01-01) [observance=Første nyttårsdag]
  if (equals=01-21) [observance=Prinsesse Ingrid Alexandra]
  if (equals=02-06) [observance=Samefolkets dag]
  if (equals=02-21) [observance=Kong Harald~V]
  if (equals=05-01) [observance=Offentlig høytidsdag]
  if (equals=05-08) [observance=Frigjøringsdagen]
  if (equals=05-17) [observance=Grunnlovsdag]
  if (equals=06-07) [observance=Unionsoppløsningen]
  if (equals=06-23) [observance=Sankthansaften]
  if (equals=07-04) [observance=Dronning Sonja]
  if (equals=07-20) [observance=Kronprins Haakon]
  if (equals=07-29) [observance=Olsok]
  if (equals=08-19) [observance=Kronprinsesse Mette-Marit]
  if (equals=10-24) [observance=FN-dagen]
  if (equals=12-25) [observance=Første juledag]
  if (equals=12-26) [observance=Andre juledag]
  if (Easter=-49) [observance=Fastelavnssøndag]
  if (Easter=-7) [observance=Palmesøndag]
  if (Easter=-3) [observance=Skjærtorsdag]
  if (Easter=-2) [observance=Langfredag]
  if (Easter) [observance=Første påskedag]
  if (Easter=1) [observance=Andre påskedag]
  if (Easter=39) [observance=Kristi himmelfartsdag]
  if (Easter=49) [observance=Første pinsedag]
  if (Easter=50) [observance=Andre pinsedag]
  if (Advent) [observance=Advent]
  if (equals=05-07) [anniversary={Brahms}{1833}]
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have any ideas about how to change the font color for the observances? Just like in the image I provided? For example, to make them look tan or brown.

Comment: You can define a new color like `\definecolor{obse}{rgb}{0.847,0.380,0.024}` and then change the pgfkey `/tikz/observance/.code` in   `\pgfkeys{/tikz/observance/.code ={\addtext{\textcolor{obse}{#1}}}}`