# Calendar in "Familienplaner" format?

Tags: german, calendar

Is there a ready-made LaTeX package that produces a calendar in a format known as *Familienplaner* in German speaking countries:

Each month is set as a table on one sheet of paper. There is one row per day, and there are additional empty columns to be filled in (between one and five, typically). Sundays are specially marked (e.g., by red colour of the date, or by a grey row instead of a white one).

Nice-to-have features: German language support for day-of-week and month names, week numbers, German holidays.

P.S. Searching the net for "Familienplaner" results in a lot of free pdf offers for such calendars.

P.P.S. The *Familienplaner* layout is different from the monthly calendar layout of this question: [Calendar in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170462/50351)

Comment: Check [tag:tikz-calendar]. There are dozens of calendar layouts just on this site that use `pgfcalendar`/TikZ. I think yours is especially easy to implement with just the right settings starting with the [`day list downward` style](https://tikz.dev/library-calender#tikz/day:list:downward).

Comment: There is a very detailed article about the `pocketdiary`context module in the TeXnische Komödie 2/2023. While it does not show a "Familienplaner", it looks very flexible. Maybe worth a shot...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you really want, you can follow the suggestion of @Qrrbrbirlbel in the comment above to your question, and reach quite fast something that could be used. Of course, having the benefits of a completely defined package is a different kind of thing.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt, paper=a3, pagesize, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,left=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german]{translator} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar} 
\def\defyear{2023}
\def\deffamilysize{4}
\def\boxsize{\dimexpr(\linewidth-3cm)/\deffamilysize}

\begin{document}

\foreach \m in {1,...,12}{
\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent\hspace*{2.98cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \person [count=\personcount] in {Paula, John, Peter, Jackie}{ %%% ENTER NAMES
        \node[xshift=3cm, draw=black,anchor=west,minimum width=\boxsize,minimum height=1.6em,xshift=\boxsize*(\personcount-1),align=center] {\person};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture} 
      \calendar [%
      dates=\defyear-\m-01 to \defyear-\m-last,%
      day list downward,%
      day yshift=1.6em,%
      month label left vertical,%
      every month/.append style={yshift=1em},%
      day code={%
        \node[anchor = east]  {\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}};
        \node[anchor = east, xshift=1.5em] {\tikzdaytext};
        \foreach \i [count=\icount] in {1,...,\deffamilysize}{
            \node[xshift=2em, anchor=west,draw=black,minimum width=\boxsize,minimum height=1.6em,xshift=\boxsize*(\icount-1)] {};}
        }
      ]
             if (Sunday) [red!75!black];
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
}   

 
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of pdf generated by code]

Comment: In case you want to extend and modify it, I opened a Github repository (https://github.com/ArneMeier/famcal), because I like the idea of these family calendars.

Comment: I extended it also a bit already. Just in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answer after one month here and own research also did not bring up such a package, I conclude that there is currently no popular calendar package for LaTeX implementing a *Familienplaner* layout.

Comment: I know that one can implement such a layout given the tools. The question explicitly asks for a ready-made package here, and it does so for a purpose (checking if an own implementation is worth the effort).