# Improve of a monthly calendar template

Tags: tikz-calendar

Someone knows how to modify the source code of the nice monthly calendar from Hakon Malmedal (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/) in the way of fill with color all the saturday, sunday and holydays? Thanks a ton!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Show us where you have a problem.

Comment: Hard to turn this “template” into a MWE…

Answer (score 1):

I added an `holyday` style that tweaks the defined `day` style (around line 400).
And use it with `if (Saturday, Sunday, equals=5-3,) [holyday]`

```
% Birthday calendar
% Author: Hakon Malmedal
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,fit}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10199/4771
\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
        \foreach \d/\l in {0/Mandag,1/Tirsdag,2/Onsdag,3/Torsdag,%
            4/Fredag,5/Lørdag,6/Søndag} {
            \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa-\cellwidth/2}%
            \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
            \node[above=-0.5ex,day heading]{\l};%
        }
    }{}%
}%
]
\makeatother%
%% End

%% Adapted from pgf source
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
    \translate{\ifcase#1\or Januar\or Februar\or Mars\or April\or
        Mai\or Juni\or Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or
        November\or Desember\fi}%
}

\makeatletter
\tikzstyle{month label above centered}=[%
execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        {
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
            \pgf@xb=\tikz@lib@cal@width\pgf@xa%
            \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa%
            \pgf@xb=.5\pgf@xb%
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%
            \pgftransformxshift{-\cellwidth/2}%
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
            \pgftransformyshift{0.333\pgf@y}
            \tikzmonthcode%
        }
    }{}},
every month/.append style={anchor=base}
]
\makeatother
%% End

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56214/4771
%%
% first of all we define the user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtext}{ m }{ \bdaycal_input_add:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtextyear}{ mm }{ \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showtext}{ }{ \bdaycal_output_direct: }

% allocate variable:
% a sequence for global storage of the inputs;
\seq_new:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq

% store globally an input in the sequence
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add:n #1
{
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 }
}

\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn #1 #2
{
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 ~ ( \int_to_arabic:n
        { \pgfcalendarifdateyear - #2 } ) }
}

% how to output in direct order; we simply do a mapping function calling
% \bdaycal_print:n after incrementing the counter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bdaycal_output_direct:
{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq
    {
        \bdaycal_print:n { ##1 }
    }
    \seq_gclear:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq
}

% the printing macro; change here for adapting to your wishes
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_print:n #1
{
    #1 \par
}
%% End

%% Knuth's AoCP, vol 1, 2nd ed, pp 155--156
\int_new:N \l_easter_Y_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_G_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_C_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_X_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_Z_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_D_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_E_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_N_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_M_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_julian_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \easter_sunday:n {

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Y_int { #1 }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_G_int {
        \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 19 } + 1
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_C_int {
        \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 100 } + 1
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_X_int {
        \int_div_truncate:nn { 3 * \l_easter_C_int } { 4 } - 12
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Z_int {
        \int_div_truncate:nn { 8 * \l_easter_C_int + 5 } { 25 } - 5
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_D_int {
        \int_div_truncate:nn { 5 * \l_easter_Y_int } { 4 } - \l_easter_X_int - 10
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_E_int {
        \int_mod:nn { 11 * \l_easter_G_int + 20 + \l_easter_Z_int
            - \l_easter_X_int } { 30 }
    }

    % \int_mod:nn behaves strangely.
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } < { 0 }
    {
        \int_add:Nn \l_easter_E_int { 30 }
    }

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_E_int } = { 25 }
    { % true
        \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_G_int } > { 11 }
        { % true
            \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
        }
    }
    { % false
        \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } = { 24 }
        { % true
            \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
        }
    }

    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 44 - \l_easter_E_int }

    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_N_int } < { 21 }
    { % true
        \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 30 }
    }

    \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int {
        7 - \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_D_int + \l_easter_N_int } { 7 }
    }

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_N_int } > { 31 }
    { % true
        \int_sub:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 31 }
        \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 4 } % April
    }
    { % false
        \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 3 } % March
    }

    \pgfcalendardatetojulian { \l_easter_Y_int -
        \l_easter_M_int - \l_easter_N_int
    } { \l_easter_julian_day_int }

}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Easter/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Easter/.code =
    {
        \easter_sunday:n { \pgfcalendarifdateyear }
        \int_compare:nNnT { \pgfcalendarifdatejulian }
        =  {\l_easter_julian_day_int + #1}
        { \pgfcalendarmatchestrue }
    }
}

\int_new:N \l_advent_Y_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int
\int_new:N \l_advent_julian_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \advent_sunday:n {

    \int_set:Nn \l_advent_Y_int { #1 }

    \pgfcalendardatetojulian { \l_advent_Y_int - 12 - 25 } {
        \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int }

    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday { \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int } {
        \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int }

    \int_set:Nn \l_advent_julian_day_int {
        \l_advent_xmas_julian_day_int - \l_advent_xmas_week_day_int - 22 }

}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Advent/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/Advent/.code =
    {
        \advent_sunday:n { \pgfcalendarifdateyear }
        \int_compare:nNnT { \pgfcalendarifdatejulian }
        =  {\l_advent_julian_day_int + #1}
        { \pgfcalendarmatchestrue }
    }
}

%% http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/week.php#calcweekno
\int_new:N \l_week_number_year_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_month_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_day_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_a_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_b_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_c_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_s_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_e_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_f_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_g_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_d_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_n_int
\int_new:N \l_week_number_W_int

\cs_new:Nn \week_number:nnn {

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_year_int { #1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_month_int { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_day_int { #3 }

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_month_int } < { 3 } % jan or feb
    { % true

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_a_int { \l_week_number_year_int - 1 }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
            \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
            - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
        }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
            \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
            - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
        }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
            \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

        \int_zero:N \l_week_number_e_int

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int - 1
            + 31 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 1 ) }

    } % end true
    { % false

        \int_set_eq:NN \l_week_number_a_int \l_week_number_year_int

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_b_int {
            \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 4 }
            - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 100 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int } { 400 }
        }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_c_int {
            \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 4 }
            - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 100 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_a_int - 1 } { 400 }
        }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_s_int {
            \l_week_number_b_int - \l_week_number_c_int }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_e_int { \l_week_number_s_int + 1 }

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_f_int { \l_week_number_day_int
            + \int_div_truncate:nn {
                153 * ( \l_week_number_month_int - 3 ) + 2 } { 5 }
            + 58 + \l_week_number_s_int }

    } % end false

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_g_int {
        \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_a_int + \l_week_number_b_int } { 7 }  }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_d_int {
        \int_mod:nn { \l_week_number_f_int + \l_week_number_g_int
            - \l_week_number_e_int } { 7 }  }

    \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_n_int {
        \l_week_number_f_int + 3 - \l_week_number_d_int }

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } < { 0 }
    { %true

        \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 53
            - \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_week_number_g_int
                - \l_week_number_s_int } { 5 } }

    } % end true
    { % false

        \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_week_number_n_int } > { 364
            + \l_week_number_s_int }
        { % true

            \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { 1 }

        } % end true
        { % false

            \int_set:Nn \l_week_number_W_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {
                    \l_week_number_n_int } { 7 } + 1 }

        } % end false

    } % end false

}

\definecolor{roed}{rgb}{0.937254901961,0.16862745098,0.176470588235}
\definecolor{blaa}{rgb}{0,0.156862745098,0.407843137255}

\newsavebox{\flagNO}
\savebox{\flagNO}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[roed] rectangle (6pt,6pt);
    \fill[roed,yshift=10pt] rectangle (6pt,6pt);
    \fill[roed,xshift=10pt] rectangle (12pt,6pt);
    \fill[roed,xshift=10pt,yshift=10pt] rectangle (12pt,6pt);
    \fill[blaa,yshift=7pt] rectangle (22pt,2pt);
    \fill[blaa,xshift=7pt] rectangle (2pt,16pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/week~number/.code =
    {
        \week_number:nnn { 
            \pgfcalendarifdateyear } { 
            \pgfcalendarifdatemonth } { 
            \pgfcalendarifdateday }
        \addtext{ Uke ~ \int_to_arabic:n { \l_week_number_W_int } }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfkeys{/tikz/flag-flying day/.code =
    {
        \draw (-\cellwidth,0) node [above right,font=\Huge]
        {\resizebox{!}{0.8ex}{\usebox{\flagNO}}};
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/observance/.code =
    {
        \addtext{#1}
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/anniversary/.code 2 args=\addtextyear{#1}{#2}}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/holyday/.code =
    {
        \node (lower right) at (0,0) [above left,font=\Huge] {\tikzdaytext};
        \node (upper left) at (-\cellwidth,\cellheight)
        [below right,align=left,text width=\cellwidth-\pgflinewidth,
        font=\tiny,black] {\showtext};
        \node (lower left) at (-\cellwidth,0) {};
        \node[rounded corners, draw,
        fit=(lower right) (upper left) (lower left),
        inner sep=1mm, fill=gray!25] {};
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day code =
    {
        \node (lower right) at (0,0) [above left,font=\Huge] {\tikzdaytext};
        \node (upper left) at (-\cellwidth,\cellheight)
        [below right,align=left,text width=\cellwidth-\pgflinewidth,
        font=\tiny,black] {\showtext};
        \node (lower left) at (-\cellwidth,0) {};
        \node[rounded corners, draw,
        fit=(lower right) (upper left) (lower left),
        inner sep=1mm] {};
    }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/inner sep = 0pt}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day xshift=\cellwidth+2mm+2mm}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day yshift=\cellheight+2mm+2mm}

\newlength{\cellheight}
\setlength{\cellheight}{25mm}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{35mm}

\begin{document}

    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \calendar[dates=2012-05-01 to 2012-05-last,
    week list,
    month label above centered,
    month text=\textsc{\%mt \%y0},
    day headings={font=\footnotesize},
    day letter headings]
    if (Saturday, Sunday,
    equals=5-3,) [holyday]
    if (Monday,
    equals=01-01,
    equals=02-01,
    equals=03-01,
    equals=04-01,
    equals=05-01,
    equals=06-01,
    equals=07-01,
    equals=08-01,
    equals=09-01,
    equals=10-01,
    equals=11-01,
    equals=12-01) [week number]
    if (Sunday,
    Easter=-3, % Maundy Thursday
    Easter=-2, % Good Friday
    Easter,    % Easter Sunday
    Easter=1,  % Easter Monday
    Easter=39, % Feast of the Ascension
    Easter=49, % Pentecost
    Easter=50, % Whit Monday
    equals=01-01,
    equals=05-01,
    equals=05-17,
    equals=12-25,
    equals=12-26) [red]
    if (equals=01-01,
    equals=01-21,
    equals=02-06,
    equals=02-21,
    equals=05-01,
    equals=05-08,
    equals=05-17,
    Easter,
    Easter=49) [flag-flying day]
    if (equals=01-01) [observance=Første nyttårsdag]
    if (equals=05-01) [observance=Offentlig høytidsdag]
    if (equals=05-08) [observance=Frigjøringsdagen]
    if (equals=05-17) [observance=Grunnlovsdag]
    if (equals=05-07) [anniversary={Brahms}{1833}]
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```