# Matching recurring date in pgfcalendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calendar

I am using a calendar heavily inspired by the one available [here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/). I am pretty happy with what I had but today, I've decided that I needed a way to match recurring dates.

I've tried the following:

```
% Definition
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.code =
  {
    \foreach \m / \d in {1/4,1/8,2/1}
      {
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=\m\relax
          \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=\d\relax
            \global\pgfcalendarmatchestrue
          \fi
        \fi
       }
  }
}

% Usage
if (recurring) [event]
```

This is working properly but it is not really practical because I need to know all the dates and include them in the loop. On top of that it is not reusable if I want to add multiple recurring events.

My idea is to change my recurring method with the following:

- adding a starting point for the day of the year (ex: *01-04* for *January 4th*).
- adding a period in days (ex: *10*).
- adding a number of events.

#### first step

My first step was to use a parameter to handle the dates instead of having them in my definition. This way I can reuse my definition with different sets of dates. It is still a lot of configuration but at least I can have one definition for multiple recurring events.

This is what I've got:

```
% Definition

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.code = 
  {
    \foreach \m/\d in {#1}
      {
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=\m\relax
          \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=\d\relax
            \global\pgfcalendarmatchestrue
          \fi
        \fi
      }
  }
}

% Usage
if (recurring={01/04,01/14,01,24}) [event]
```

#### second step

My second step was to compute the dates with the starting point, the period and the number of events. As I can not know the month and day of the event, I've decided to compute everything using Julian dates. This is what I've got:

```
% Definition
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.code 3 args={3} 
  {
    \foreach \events in {0,..,#3}
      {
        \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-#1+#2*\events}{\jul}
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatejulian=\jul\relax
          \global\pgfcalendarmatchestrue
        \fi
      }
  }
}

% Usage
if (recurring={01-04}{14}{3}) [event]
```

The first parameter is start date, the second parameter is the period, and the third parameter is the number of events.

And that's where I am stuck. Nothing is working.
In texmaker I have the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgf@temp.
<to be read again>
3
l.310 }
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Is there something I can do to fix that? Do I use a completely wrong path to achieve what I would like to?

#### Edit #1

Here is a working example with the last working solution:

```
% Birthday calendar
% Author: Hakon Malmedal
\documentclass[fontsize=20pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Birthday calendar
:Tags: Calendar library;Calendars
:Author: Hakon Malmedal
:Slug: birthday-calendar
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,fit}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10199/4771
\makeatletter%
\tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
\tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
\tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
      \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
      \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
      \foreach \d/\l in {0/Lundi,1/Mardi,2/Mercredi,3/Jeudi,%
                         4/Vendredi,5/Samedi,6/Dimanche} {
        \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa-\cellwidth/2}%
        \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
        \node[above=-0.5ex,day heading]{\l};%
      }
    }{}%
  }%
]
\makeatother%
%% End

%% Adapted from pgf source
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%
  \translate{\ifcase#1\or Janvier\or Février\or Mars\or Avril\or
    Mai\or Juin\or Juillet\or Août\or Septembre\or Octobre\or
    Novembre\or Decembre\fi}%
}

\makeatletter
\tikzstyle{month label above centered}=[%
  execute before day scope={%
    \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
      {
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgf@xb=\tikz@lib@cal@width\pgf@xa%
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa%
        \pgf@xb=.5\pgf@xb%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xb}%
        \pgftransformxshift{-\cellwidth/2}%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgftransformyshift{0.333\pgf@y}
        \tikzmonthcode%
      }
    }{}},
  every month/.append style={anchor=base}
]
\makeatother
%% End

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56214/4771
%%
% first of all we define the user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtext}{ m }{ \bdaycal_input_add:n { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtextyear}{ mm }{ \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showtext}{ }{ \bdaycal_output_direct: }

% allocate variable:
% a sequence for global storage of the inputs;
\seq_new:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq

% store globally an input in the sequence
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add:n #1
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_input_add_y:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq { #1 ~ ( \int_to_arabic:n
    { \pgfcalendarifdateyear - #2 } ) }
 }

% how to output in direct order; we simply do a mapping function calling
% \bdaycal_print:n after incrementing the counter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bdaycal_output_direct:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_bdaycal_input_seq
   {
    \bdaycal_print:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_bdaycal_input_seq
 }

% the printing macro; change here for adapting to your wishes
\cs_new:Npn \bdaycal_print:n #1
 {
  #1 \par
 }
%% End

%% Knuth's AoCP, vol 1, 2nd ed, pp 155--156
\int_new:N \l_easter_Y_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_G_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_C_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_X_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_Z_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_D_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_E_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_N_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_M_int
\int_new:N \l_easter_julian_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \easter_sunday:n {

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Y_int { #1 }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_G_int {
    \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 19 } + 1
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_C_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { \l_easter_Y_int } { 100 } + 1
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_X_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 3 * \l_easter_C_int } { 4 } - 12
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_Z_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 8 * \l_easter_C_int + 5 } { 25 } - 5
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_D_int {
    \int_div_truncate:nn { 5 * \l_easter_Y_int } { 4 } - \l_easter_X_int - 10
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_E_int {
    \int_mod:nn { 11 * \l_easter_G_int + 20 + \l_easter_Z_int
      - \l_easter_X_int } { 30 }
  }

  % \int_mod:nn behaves strangely.
  \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } < { 0 }
  {
    \int_add:Nn \l_easter_E_int { 30 }
  }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_E_int } = { 25 }
  { % true
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_G_int } > { 11 }
    { % true
      \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
    }
  }
  { % false
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_E_int } = { 24 }
    { % true
      \int_incr:N \l_easter_E_int
    }
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 44 - \l_easter_E_int }

  \int_compare:nNnT { \l_easter_N_int } < { 21 }
  { % true
    \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 30 }
  }

  \int_add:Nn \l_easter_N_int {
    7 - \int_mod:nn { \l_easter_D_int + \l_easter_N_int } { 7 }
  }

  \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_easter_N_int } > { 31 }
  { % true
    \int_sub:Nn \l_easter_N_int { 31 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 4 } % April
  }
  { % false
    \int_set:Nn \l_easter_M_int { 3 } % March
  }

  \pgfcalendardatetojulian { \l_easter_Y_int -
     \l_easter_M_int - \l_easter_N_int
  } { \l_easter_julian_day_int }

}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\pgfkeys{/tikz/event/.code = \addtext{#1}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.default = 0}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/calendar/recurring/.code = 
  {
    \foreach \m/\d in {#1}
      {
        \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatemonth=\m\relax
          \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdateday=\d\relax
            \global\pgfcalendarmatchestrue
          \fi
        \fi
      }
   }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day code =
  {
    \node (lower right) at (0,0) [above left,font=\Large] {\tikzdaytext};
    \node (upper left) at (-\cellwidth,\cellheight)
    [below right,align=left,text width=\cellwidth-\pgflinewidth,
    font=\tiny,black] {\showtext};
    \node (lower left) at (-\cellwidth,0) {};
    \node[rounded corners, draw,
          fit=(lower right) (upper left) (lower left),
          inner sep=1mm] {};
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/inner sep = 0pt}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day xshift=\cellwidth+2mm+2mm}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/day yshift=\cellheight+2mm+2mm}

\newlength{\cellheight}
\setlength{\cellheight}{25mm}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{35mm}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \calendar[dates=2024-01-01 to 2024-01-last,
            week list,
            month label above centered,
            month text=\textsc{\%mt \%y0},
            day headings={font=\footnotesize},
            day letter headings]
    if (recurring={01/04,01/14,01/24}) [event={Something}]
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't taken a closer look at what you're trying to do but a `.code` only accepts one argument. If you want to use three, you need to use `.code n args={3}{<code>}`. (And the default needs to be three arguments as well if you want it to work.)

Comment: I've updated my code and this question with your suggestion

Comment: Read @Qrrbrbirlbel 's comment again. `.code 3 args` isn't a defined handler (that I know of). `code n args` is. And please provide complete code we can compile to reproduce the error.

Comment: `\pgfcalendardatetojulian` doesn't take arguments in the format you're passing. The first argument needs to be of the `<year>-<month>-<day>+<number>`form. So `{01-14}`. But I think you'll probably find you need an auxiliary function or some other way of expanding it first. You can't just stick a count into a comparison like that. Don't you need `\thejul`? I'm assuming here that `\jul` **is** a TeX counter, which it isn't possible to determine from what you've shown.

Comment: Rather than cycle through dates, given the start date and the test date, all you need is the difference between their julian day numbers. Then see if that is modulo the period.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @cfr, at the time, I didn't defined a counter for ```\jul```. But even when defining it, it does not work. I've tried with ```\thejul``` and ```\value{jul}``` without success.

Comment: @A.D.  Note that it wants a TeX count, if I remember correctly, and not a LaTeX counter. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Use `\tikzset` instead. Is that really the smallest example which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `recurring` test with the syntax

```
recurring = occurrences times from date every repeat [days|weeks]
```

where

- `date` is a date in the usual calendar syntax `YYYY-MM-DD` where the `YYYY-` is optional,
- `occurrences` is the number of times the event should be repeated (in addition to the very first at `date`),
- `repeat` is the number between recurring events and
- [**days**|**weeks**] is either `days` or `weeks`.

The key words `times`, `days` and `weeks` can be singular `time`, `day` and `week`.

The value of `repeat` will be evaluated by PGFMath (so could be `8-2^2`) where as `occurrences` will only be evaluated by eTeX (`8-2*2` would work).

Your event at the fourth, the fourteenth and the the twentyforth of January would be

```
recurring = 2 times from 01-04 every 10 days
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar}{
  recurring/.code args={#1 time#2 from #3 every #4 #5}{%
    % This macro converts yyyy-mm-dd to julian date (in \pgfutil@tempctna)
    % as well as mm-dd with the current year
    \pgfcalendar@special@datetojulian{#3}%
    \pgfqkeys{/pgf/calendar/@recurring}{#5={#4}{#1}}},
  @recurring/days/.code 2 args={% #1 is the every, #2 is the times
    \ifnum\pgfintmod{\pgfcalendarifdatejulian-\pgfutil@tempcnta}{#1}=0
      \pgfmathsetcount\c@pgf@counta{#2}%
      \unless\ifnum\pgfintdivtruncate
        {\pgfcalendarifdatejulian-\pgfutil@tempcnta}{#1}>\c@pgf@counta
        \pgfcalendarmatchestrue
      \fi
    \fi},
  @recurring/weeks/.style 2 args={/pgf/calendar/@recurring/days={7*(#1)}{#2}},
  @recurring/day/.style={/pgf/calendar/@recurring/days={#1}},
  @recurring/week/.style={/pgf/calendar/@recurring/weeks={#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \calendar[
    dates=2023-01-01 to 2023-03-31,
    month list, month label left, month yshift=1.25em]
  if (Sunday) [days={fill=red!50}]
  if (recurring = 17 times from 2023-01-01 every  2 days)  [green!50!black]
  if (recurring =  4 times from 2023-02-06 every  2 weeks) [blue!50]
  if (recurring =  2 times from      01-04 every 10 days)  [days={fill=green!50}];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I'll check that later. There is no way I could have figured something like that with my current knowledge.

Comment: It works like a charm. At first, I've messed up my document and it started to use all resources available. But with the proper document it works as intended. I am now left with the task of understanding the syntax completely because at the moment I can only understand at a higher level. Thank you for the huge help and for the opportunity to learn something new.