# Auto-resize delimiters without `\left`, `\right` usage

Tags: math-mode, luatex, expl3, delimiters

When I looked for a solution to auto-resize pairs of delimiters without using `\left` and `\right` I found this topic: [auto-resizing parenthesis in math formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289542/auto-resizing-parenthesis-in-math-formulas). It works as expected but it can't be used inside e.g `align` due to `&` and `\\`. Is there any way to make it work with `align`-like enviromnents?

I have tried to solve this issue in dumb way using some workaround from `mathtools` manual:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,unicode-math,xparse}

\newcommand*\autoop{\lrparen(}
\newcommand*\autoob{\lrbrack[}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \mathcode`( 32768
    \mathcode`[ 32768
    \begingroup
        \lccode`\~`(
        \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \let~\autoop}
    \begingroup
        \lccode`\~`[
        \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \let~\autoob}
}

\delimiterfactor 1001

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode`\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\lrparen{d()}{
\mathopen{\left(\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#1
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\right)}}

\NewDocumentCommand\lrbrack{o}{
\mathopen{\left[\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#1
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#1}}\right]}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        [[ ( a,\\ b ) ]]
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but it fix only line break problem. Last answer in mentioned topic use some sort of queue or stack, so I wonder if this problem could be solved by `expl3` or `luatex` because I don't see the way to rewrite original answer to play with `align` and friends.

Comment: even without align it is almost always better to use manually chosen sizes with `\biggl(` rather than `\left(` so there is very little call for this. `breqn` may be the nearest thing to this that is available `out of the box`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle does `breqn` actually do that? Isn't it `nath` that could do autoscaling of everything, but then again `nath` is incompatible with almost everything.

Comment: @daleif er I'd need to check:-)  If you are asking then possibly not....

Comment: what do you mean by `fix only line break problem` ? doesn't your scantokens make `&` safe during the measuring part? You don't give an example using `&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In original topic we can't use `\\ `. In my solution `\\ ` works but `&` throw errors. Try `[[ ( &a,\\ &b ) ]]` inside `align`.